# How to compile JSVM reference implementation in 2022?

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

I need to compile the JSVM reference implementation. The code can be found here: https://vcgit.hhi.fraunhofer.de/jvet/jsvm

The instructions included say one should use gcc version 4:

```
# Building the JSVM software under Linux with a gcc compiler (version 4)
cd JSVM/H264AVCExtension/build/linux
make
```

However, I did not succeed to install the correct version of gcc on ubuntu 22.04.

Another thing I tried is to spin up a vm with ubuntu 10.04.4 to compile JSVM there, but apt-get was not working in the VM (are the servers no longer running?), so I could not install g++.

Comment: Yeah, even Ubuntu LTS is end-of-life at some point. There probably is some old archive server somewhere - good luck! I'd honestly rather try to port this software to a modern GCC.

Comment: @MarcusMüller unfortunately my C skills are not sufficient for that...

Comment: So, how did you verify it doesn't work with a less ancient GCC?

Comment: @MarcusMüller By trying to compile it. I managed to find an updated version that compiles with modern tools here https://github.com/floriandejonckheere/jsvm